# SSH to Kubernetes pod using Bastion

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, google-kubernetes-engine

I have deployed Google cloud Kubernetes cluster. The cluster has internal IP only.

In order to access it, I created a virtual machine `bastion-1` which has external IP.

The structure:

```
My Machine -> bastion-1 -> Kubernetes cluster
```

The connection to the proxy station:

```
$ ssh bastion -D 1080
```

now using `kubectl` using proxy:

```
$ HTTPS_PROXY=socks5://127.0.0.1:1080 kubectl get pods
No resources found.
```

The Kubernetes master server is responding, which is a good sign.

Now, trying to ssh a pod:

```
$ HTTPS_PROXY=socks5://127.0.0.1:1080 kubectl exec -it "my-pod" -- /bin/bash
error: error sending request: Post https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/v1/namespaces/xxx/pods/pod-xxx/exec?command=%2Fbin%2Fbash&container=xxx&container=xxx&stdin=true&stdout=true&tty=true: EOF
```

Question: 
How to allow ssh connection to pod via bastion? What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this right now.

The reason is because the connections used for commands like exec and proxy use SPDY2.

There's a bug report [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/58065) with more information.

You'll have to switch to using a HTTP proxy

Comment: Better SOCKS support for `kubectl exec` may be coming soon, however: I found that installing `tinyproxy` on the SSH server works beautifully ([instructions that thread](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/58065#issuecomment-499580806)). After that, just tweak `HTTPS_PROXY` setting to point to `http://` (instead of `socks5://`).